# Facebook Application Send Friend request using Facebook Api

Tags: facebook

I want to send Facebook friend invitations to some of our friends list without using FBML tags (`<fb:request ....`)

I am writing code in ASP.NET using fbServices.

How can I send friend requests without using FMBL tags?

Answer (score 7):

Friend requests cannot be done through the Facebook API. The FBML [fb:request-form](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:request-form) tag is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I spent a great deal of time looking, and finally came accross a very simple solution.

Using the Facebook Javascript API you can do a friend request with:

```
<script>
    FB.ui(
     { 
      method: 'friends.add', 
      id: fbid // assuming you set this variable previously...
     }, 
     function(param){

      console.log(param);

            // If they cancel params will show: 
            //    {action:false, ...}
            // and if they send the friend request it'll have:
            //    {action:true, ...}
            // and if they closed the pop-up window then:
            //    param is undefined
     }
    );
</script>
```

The callback script can then simply performs an ajax call to your server where 
you save info about the action, if needed.

You can test this by using the javascript console app on Facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console

Paste in the script above, including the  tags, or click the "Examples"
button on the bottom of the text area and find the "fb.ui — friends.add" example.

Answer (score 3):

fb:request-form is now obsolete and will be deprecated eventually. The new way, [announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453) on 27 January 2011, is the [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow you to programatically send friend requests.

I suggest taking a look at their API

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Years later, things has changed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

> Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface to provide social
>   functionality to your users. Dialogs do not require any additional
>   permissions because they require user interaction. Dialogs can be used
>   by your application in every context: within a Canvas Page, in a Page
>   Tab, in a website or mobile web app, and within native iOS and native
>   Android applications.
>
> **There are currently 7 Dialogs available for you to use:**
>   - The Feed Dialog allows a user to post a story to their Timeline and to their friends' News Feeds
>   - The OAuth Dialog allows a user to authorize an application as part of an authentication flow.
>   - The Add Page Tab Dialog allows a user to add an application to a Facebook Page which they administer.
>   - The Friends Dialog allows a user to send a friend request to another user.
>   - The Pay Dialog allows a user to make a purchase using Facebook Credits.
>   - The Requests Dialog allows a user to send a request to one or more of their friends
>   - The Send Dialog allows a user to send a Facebook Message to one or more of their friends.

See also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Answer (score -2):

You can send requests to friends without using FBML as follows

```
`FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'This is my applicaiton',
                title: 'Application Request without FBML',
                filters: 'all'
              },
                                // Callback function returning the list of requestObj Ids
                function(response){

                }
        );`
```

```
For more info  you could refer 
 Wiki Page for apprequest graph API
```