# Facebook send friend request

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Application Send Friend request using Faceboook Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304866/facebook-application-send-friend-request-using-faceboook-api)

I am developing facebook application . In that i want to send friends request using javascript (FBJS) .

plz any one help me

Thanks